# How to execute *ngIf-else of else condition only once?

Tags: angular

I iterate through an array in a div with *ngFor. Inside this div there is another div with an *ngIf else condition, where the else condition matches 25 values.

My query is that instead of 25 values, I want to print only the first value, while the other 24 values should be hidden or ignored. Note that the other 25 values that match the if-statement should all be visible. How it is possible?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of messageArray; let index = index">
  <div *ngIf="userids == item.userid;else other_content">{{item.username}}</div>
  <ng-template #other_content>{{item.username}}</ng-template>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
constructor(private socketService : SocketserviceService) { 
  this.socketService.newMessageReceived().subscribe((data) => {
    this.messageArray = data.payload;
  });
};
```

Comment: Why don't you just print the first value of the array? messageArray[0]

Comment: but else codition 1st value how it is possible?

Comment: Things like that happens when you violate MVVM or MVC.

Comment: I would check the thing in the ts file. And return a boolean value of show/notShow. Then add your code inside of an ngIf. It makes no sense to write this kind of logic in the html in my opinion

Comment: Do you want to print all userids == item.userid; values but userids != item.userid first value?

Comment: @Asanka yes exactly

Comment: In your typescript component create array which only holds your the messages you want to display. Don't do much logic in your View! Do it instead in your controller (typescriptFile). And if you want to display more, alter your array again

Comment: Can you show the Method which get  messageArray?

Comment: @Asanka i edited my question

Comment: It's not clear at all that you still want to print all `userids == item.userid` in your original question

Comment: You have to put else outside the loop

Comment: @AmishaRana Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

app.component.ts

```
userNamePrintInElse =""
constructor(private socketService : SocketserviceService) { 
  this.socketService.newMessageReceived().subscribe((data) => {
    this.messageArray.push(data);userids
    this.userNamePrintInElse = this.messageArray.filter(data => data.userid != this.userids )[0].username
  });
};
```

in Html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of messageArray; let index = index">
  <div *ngIf="userids == item.userid">{{item.username}}</div>
</div>
  <div >{{userNamePrintInElse}}</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of the loop itself with the `first` operator :

```js
<div *ngFor="let item of messageArray; let index = index; first as isFirst">
  <div *ngIf="isFirst>{{item.username}}</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Now that I have understood your question : you can't do what you want in the template only.

In order to achieve what you want, you will be forced to create two getters : one for the message respecting the condition, one for the others.

```js
get messagesWithIdMatch() {
  return this.messageArray.filter(item => item.userid === this.userids);
}

getFirstMessageWithoutIdMatch {
  return this.messageArray.filter(item => item.userid !== this.userids)[0];
}
```

Now your HTML becomes this :

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of messagesWithIdMatch">
  <div>{{item.username}}</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    {{ getFirstMessageWithoutIdMatch.username }}
  </div>
</div>
```

This will display the 25 items matching your condition, and will display only the first item not matching it.

Comment: but i want if condition all values only else condition first value want

Comment: Please make an effort in your English. I already didn't quite get the first question, but this comment is just blurry ... What is your original condition ?

Comment: sorry for my english i have 50 values in *ngFor and inside else condtion i have 25 value among 25 values i want to print 1st value only of else condition

Comment: Ok so in what other variable are stored the 25 values ? You have 50 values in `messageArray`, and 25 in ?

Comment: 25 in if condition and 25 in else conditon.

Comment: triche is this possible to print only first value of if *ngIf

Answer (score 1):

The *ngIf and *ngFor directives are mostly here for display purpose. If you want to supply any logic, then you should avoid doing it inside your template.

Split your array inside your component and then display it via two different directives inside your component.

```
public otherElement: any = _.first(messageArray)
public filteredArray: any[] = _.filter(messageArray, item => item.id != otherElement.id)
```

You will have yout "otherElement" and your "filteredArray" already set.
You can then display them like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of filteredArray; let index = index">
  <ng-container>
    <div>{{item.username}}</div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
<ng-template #other_content>{{otherElement.username}}</ng-template>
```